# Lodash method to check whether all elements in an array are in another array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have 2 arrays of string. I want to make sure all elements of the second array are in the first. I use Lodash/Underscore for things like this. Its easy when checking if one astring is in an array:

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
_.includes(arr1, 'b');
// => true
```

But when its an array, I cant see a current method to do it. What I've done is:

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'x'];

var intersection = _.intersection(arr1, arr2);

console.log('intersection is ', intersection);

if (intersection.length < arr2.length) {
    console.log('no');
} else {
    console.log('yes');
}
```

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/654rcurq/). But its rather long-winded. Is there a built in Lodash method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`_.xor`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#xor) for a symmetric difference and take the length as check. If `length === 0`, the both arrays contains the same elements.

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'x'];

console.log(_.xor(arr2, arr1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```